# How to reference an array from another function in c?

Tags: c, reference

I have two functions. The first function below called, "readFile," takes a file from a command line argument entered by the user, reads the text, and puts it into a dynamic char array called 'str.' This function compiles without error, details are omitted for simplicity. The function then returns 'str'.

```
char *readFile(char *filename) {

  ...
  return str;
}
```

My second function below must use that array for various operations, the details are not important as they are not the issue.

```
int findValues(int words, int chars, int lines) {

  //what to enter to reference 'str' from readFile to work with its contents??
}
```

I cannot change the arguments/parameters within 'findValues.' So how do I reference the array 'str' from 'readFile' so I can work with the contents within the array? Thanks

Comment: In a decent design, you'd pass it as an argument. If this is for a class or something and doesn't let you do that... global variable?

Comment: Short of a global variable, there is no way,  but then you wouldn't need to allocate it to the heap, unless it's quite large. nor to return it from readFile, it makes little sense. It should be passed as a parameter, that's what they are for.

Comment: I wonder if the instructors themselves try to solve their assignments before giving them to the students :(

Comment: Thank you all for your comments, just going to add a parameter!